1960s Stylesheet/Format for working Physics problems
One of my Physics professors once mentioned that he took a semester-long Physics class that was all about formatting work in the correct way: The problems were done on graph/grid paper, and all of the numbers had to be written in uniform way like a blueprint. At the end, a box had to be drawn around the answer and points were deducted if the lines of the box extended beyond the corners of the grid and didn't meet exactly. I'd estimate that it was probably around the early 1960s when he took this class.
This was just an offhand tangent in one of his lectures, but it always stuck with me. Is anyone familiar with this formal way to work Physics problems? There must have been a lot more to it if the class lasted an entire semester, and I'm trying to find a textbook or style guide or whatever might have been used as reference for this kind of class.
(I think this is the right place to post this, as it doesn't have to do with Physics itself.)

You probably want a book on "Engineering Drawing" or similar from that era. I also took such a physics class in the early 60s. Computer graphics software has replaced this, but it wasn't available then and was how we got some precision.
I actually found it to be fun, though that is a long-ago memory.
If I remember correctly, the professor's blackboard (yes, with chalk) were very precise.
Your university library might just possibly have such a book from those days.

Can you recommend some titles to begin the journey? Books around  60s likely will be available on archive.org.
